# Relation between being holomorphic in $\Delta\times\Delta$ and in every relatively compact polydisk.

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I asked to some professors of my university and no one was able to help me (the one who held the course is abroad for a period, otherwise I'd ask him, obviously).

My problem is that simply I don't understand the first sentence of the proof of Theorem 1.5.3 (you can see below) at all:

- Thesis is: $f\in\operatorname{hol}(\Delta\times\Delta)$: why from proving $f$ is holomorphic on every relatively compact polydisc should the thesis follows?
- What is a relatively compact polydisk?
- In which space are there polydisks relatively compact?
- Why does since we have to prove that $f$ is holomorphic on every relatively compact polydisc imply that we can take $f$ holomorphic on a strip slightly bigger than $\Delta\times\Delta_{\varepsilon}$ (morover: I think a slightly bigger strip is $\Delta_{1+\delta}\times\Delta_{\delta+\varepsilon}$, for some $\delta>0$: is this correct?).

[image]

If you can help me to shade some light on it I would be very grateful. I'm going crary about this. Many many thanks.

**EDIT** In order to be clearer, I'm posting some more material, hoping someone can help.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's unclear to me which of the following you're asking: (i) Why is $f$ holomorphic in a polydisk if it's holomorphic in every relatively compact (i.e., compactly contained?) polydisk; (ii) How to see that if $f$ is holomorphic on the strip in the theorem, it's holomorphic on a slightly larger strip; (iii) How your book deduces, "Since we have to prove..., we can assume..."; (iv) Something else about the proof of Theorem 1.5.3. (For what it's worth, the wording of that first sentence in the book's proof looks peculiar to me.)

Comment: @user86418: many thanks, I edited my post, in order to explain my problems, with respect to the points you pointed out (sorry for the bad word joke!:-) ). Thanks

Comment: If I guess correctly, this is a step in the proof of Hartogs theorem about separate analyticity. There you take a domain $U$ and prove that $f$ is holomorphic on every relatively compact polydisc. If this is the situation, you have that the hypotheses hold in a neighbourhood of the polydisc, so that you can enlarge the strip a bit.

Comment: @wisefool: yes, this is the last step of Hartogs Theorem. Can you explain your argument with a little more detail please? It seems the right way

Comment: @user86418:(i) should be clear since a polydisk can be obtained as union of all the polydiscs contained in it; the only question is what does "compactly contained" mean? Because of the definition I know of "relatively compact" subset, every polydisks contained in a given polydisk are relatively compact, hence it seems redundant to underline this. But this author is very precise, hence if he writes something, there must exists a reason. And I can't understand why he wrote that.

Comment: @user86418:(ii) and (iii), absolutely: they are the point. But: is (ii) true? If $f$ is holomorphic on a given strip, why should it be holomorphic even on slightly bigger strip?!

Moreover the conclusion of (ii) and (iii) seems to be the same: $f$ is holomorphic on a slightly larger strip. So I can't understand why you thought at these two different questions!

However, in general the problem is precisely that first sentence. It is very important (because the rest of the proof is based on it), but it is not clear.

Comment: @Joe For a bounded polydisk $D$, being relatively compact in some set $M$ means that the closure of $D$ - with respect to $\mathbb{C}^n$ - is contained in $M$. If $M$ is an open polydisk, that means $D$ "stays away from the boundary of $M$". Take $n = 1$ for simplicity, then if the boundary circles touch, the smaller disk is not relatively compact in the larger.

Comment: @Joe: Didn't mean to abandon your question, just unsure I have anything useful to add. (The distinction between my questions (ii) and (iii) is hair-splitting: Question (ii) is a mathematical question (is some statment true); question (iii) concerns the peculiar wording, "Since we have to prove that..., we can assume..." (is the assertion logically justified).)

Is it possible the author "meant" to write, "Since we _want_ to prove $f$ is holomorphic on every relatively compact polydisc, _it suffices to show_ $f$ is in fact holomorphic over a slightly bigger strip"?

Comment: @DanielFischer and user86418: before going on we have to be clear about the "slightly bigger strip": does it mean something like $\Delta\times\Delta_{\varepsilon+\delta}$ OR $\Delta_{1+\delta}\times\Delta_{\varepsilon+\delta}$? I think (and hope, otherwise the remaining part of the proof would have been screwed up) we mean the second. Thanks again, guys, I'm going crazy studying for this exam

Comment: @Joe: The interpretation of "slightly bigger strip" has to be the former, $\Delta \times \Delta_{\varepsilon+\delta}$: $f$ is, ultimately, holomorphic on $\Delta \times \Delta$, but not generally on any larger polydisk.

Comment: @user86418: yes, ultimately $f$ is holomorphic in $\Delta\times\Delta$, but supposing $f$ holomorphic on $\Delta_{1+\delta}\times\Delta_{\varepsilon+\delta}$ *does not* force the final result to be more general (i.e. $f$ hol on $\Delta_{1+\varepsilon}\times\Delta$), or not?

Comment: @Joe: Not sure what you're asking in the last comment, but if it helps: It's possible for a function to be holomorphic on $\Delta \times \Delta$, but not on any strictly larger open set.<br /><br /> Ultimately, your only recourse may be to examine the book's proof yourself and see what actual hypotheses get used and what actual conclusion gets proven; in the context of the passage you've posted, I can't understand what the author means. Wish I could be of more assistance....

Comment: @user86418: thanks for your patience and attention, really. I edited my post, I attached some more material from my book. Till the point we are talking about, I understood everything, even if it wasn't easy (by the way: how do you find it? easy? difficult? normal? I studied from analytic number theory books as Titchmarsh and Davenport.. but they wasn't cryptical and difficult as this one, IMHO).